# C# dynamic is {} vs is object

Tags: c#, pattern-matching

I came across a weird behavior in C#

The following code fails to compile

```
dynamic? x;
//... initialize x
if(x is {} y && y.z == 1){
  Console.WriteLine(y);
}
```

with error `use of unassigned local variable y` in the WriteLine

All of the following variations however do compile

```
dynamic? x;
if(x is {} y){
  if(y.z == 1){
    Console.WriteLine(y);
  }
}
```

<s>```
dynamic? x;
if(x is object y && y.z == 1){
  Console.WriteLine(y);
}
```</s>

```
mytype? x; //mytype is a class that defines an int z
if(x is {} y && y.z == 1){
  Console.WriteLine(y);
}
```

So what is special about the combination of `dynamic`, `is {}` and using a single if that makes this not compile?

Comment: Do you _need_ to use `dynamic` here?

Comment: With the `is {}`, are you only validating that `x` is not null?

Comment: @gunr2171 Does that matter? I'm not looking to solve a specific problem, just to understand what's going on. With the `is {}` I am indeed only validating that it is not null.

Comment: Not exactly. You are also casting it and going on to use the casted result. Just to be a little nitpicky here. But I have the feeling that detail may contain the solution somehow.

Comment: Sure, but that is also done in the `mytype` snippet.

Comment: The `dynamic?` is a nullable object, whereas `{}` is non-nullable.

Comment: pretty sure `if(x is object y && y.z == 1)` doesn't compile... `object.z` ?

Comment: you are right. I made a mistake in that snippet. It does however compile if we don't use z but a method that object defines, say ToString. But I guess that is not interesting since it is just casting it to object.

Answer (score 1):

This *feels* like it could be a pattern matching bug in the compiler - it is very odd; I'll need to check the language spec! However, the IDE reports `y` as `dynamic?`, which seems unusual but ... is consistent with what the compiler says.

There *is* a terse syntax that you might prefer:

```
if (x?.z == 1)
{
    // cast here is to avoid dynamic invoke, since we know it isn't a
    // simple type (because of the .z)
    Console.WriteLine((object)x);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

My opinion can be wrong but I think other variations can be compiled because x is not initialized there. So `x is {}` always return false. So other kind of code with `y` even don`t compile because it will be never be used

Comment: see `//... initialize x`

Comment: He initialized x in other variations? I just thought that he didnt do it